Why audio use blob url can not play in IOS17
i tranform audio online resource to blob Url , and set audio src, however audio cannot play in IOS 17,
ios < 17 ,can play audio.
i try to tranform blob to base64 ，but base64 volume is bigger, when base64 is large ,it cannot play same.

problem seem to occur on iphone 15pro & IOS17.4, problem maybe related with device? when i use iphone 11 or 15 with IOS17.4 ,its ok .

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
